# How to handle a change in the published abstract base class?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I have developed a "Kennel" application which takes care of various kinds of Dogs. My clients are expected to admit their Dogs to my application to avail the services.

So, I had defined a generic "Dog" interface. The clients need to implement the interface to create a concrete Dog type (Say Labrador, Poodle, etc), instantiate them and admit them to my kennel application(using say, `kennel::admitDog(dog *dog`).

Here is the Dog abstract base class:

```
class Dog {
public:
    Dog()
    {

    }

    virtual ~Dog()
    {

    }

    virtual void eatFood() = 0;
    virtual void takeBath() = 0;
    virtual void play() = 0;
    virtual void sleep() = 0;
};
```

I published this Interface and my clients already started using it to create their own concrete Dog types. In the next version of the application, I am planning to support robotic dogs in the kennel.

Here comes the problem. The robotic dogs needs `Dog::rechargeBattery()` in the above abstract base class. And, it doesnt need the existing `Dog::eatFood()` function. Adding the `Dog::rechargeBattery()` to the above abstract base class would affect all the existing clients who are already using this interface. They will be forced to implement the `Dog::rechargeBattery()` and recompile. This may not be desirable.

1. What is the solution at this point?
2. What should I have been done in the initial design to have this problem prevented?

Comment: Remove `eatFood` from `Dog` and add `LiveDog` and `RobotDog` derived abstract classes?

Comment: @NeilButterworth But, removing `eatFood` would affect the existing clients. All of them will be forced to implement `LiveDog`

Comment: Yes, it was a comment on #2.  But for #1 it looks like some redesign and re-implementation will be necessary - such is life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
class Dog {
    virtual void eatFood() = 0;
    virtual void takeBath() = 0;
    virtual void play() = 0;
    virtual void sleep() = 0;
};

class Kennel {
    void admit (Dog*);
}
```

Becomes this:

```
class DogLike {
    // virtual void eatFood() = 0; <-- removed
    virtual void takeBath() = 0;
    virtual void play() = 0;
    virtual void sleep() = 0;
};

class Dog : public DogLike {
    virtual void eatFood() = 0; // <-- added
};

class RoboticDog : public DogLike {
    virtual void rechargeBatteries() = 0;
};

class Kennel {
    void admit (DogLike*);
};
```

Existing clients should be source-compatible (but almost certainly not binary-compatible) with your modified library. Achieving binary compatibility may or may not be possible, but that's the case with any change to the published `Dog` class.

Since clients supposedly know what kind of dog they are handing to the kennel, it is possible to modify the kennel interface to separate live dogs from robotic dogs:

```
class Kennel {
  public:
    void admit (Dog*);
    void admit (RoboticDog*);
};
```

Other kinds of dogs will not be admitted.

What's next? Supposedly the kennel has facilities to serve all who answer the DogLike interface, and separate facilities for live dogs and for robotic dogs.

```
void Kennel::admit (Dog* dog) {
    commonFacilities.admit(dog);
    messHall.admit(dog);
}

void Kennel::admit (RoboticDog* dog) {
    commonFacilities.admit(dog);
    chargingStation.admit(dog);
}
```

Still no cast in sight. If it is undesirable to have two public `admit` methods, one can hide them behind a façade that inspects dynamic types behind the scenes.

```
class Kennel {
    void admit (Dog*);
    void admit (RoboticDog*);
  public:
    void admit (DogLike* dog) {
      if (auto d = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(dog)) 
        admit (d);
      else if (auto d = dynamic_cast<RoboticDog*>(dog)) 
        admit (d);
      else
        throw UnknownDogTypeError;
    }
};
```

Comment: How would a kennel feed or recharge a DogLike object? I.e. how could the appropriate method be called, based on e.g. a pointer to DogLike?

Comment: @Yunnosch it's a very good question. Kennel can use dynamic_cast to differentiate between different types of dogs. I know it is a dirty solution, but realistically different kinds of dogs eat different types and amounts of food, so the kennel would need to come up with a way of classifying dogs anyway. Alternatively, one can just declare that electricity is the kind of food robotic dogs eat, and sidestep this entire problem.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. Would you like to show how you would do that? The other answers have a part to demonstrate that, and I think they are more helpful that way. Maybe you can show how to do it in the least dirty way.

Comment: @Yunnosch We can ask two questions. (1). How to design the entire system from scratch so that it can deal with the two or more slightly incompatible kinds of dogs? (2). Given an existing design, how to change it in the least painful way in order to achive a state that approaches (1)? I didn't try to answer (1) at all, it's not what was asked. I just tried to keep the two classes clean and separate. A solution to (1) that assumes separate classes should be possible to implement on top of my answer.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the answer. Actually, I had asked on the how this problem could be prevented in first place. Please refer my question #2. If possible, can you please edit your answer to include how the original design should have been.

Answer (score 0):

Both questions can be answered the same, i.e. you still can implement a design to solve the problem now and prevent it for the future. In order to handle different classes (dogs in your example) which implement different subsets of operations, simply add an API to find out what they can/need. The handler/client (kennel in your example) is then able to find out what they can/need and call accordingly.

This is a more transparent design than determining the needs/capabilities based on being aware of all possible derived classes and what each of them can/need.

Consider this approach. "I can tell that you are a robot (because you reek of oil), so I will charge your battery. You (other) have salivated all over me, so you seem to be a biological dog, that is why I will feed you."
Compare it to "Do you want food? Nice sausage? Ah, you beg, so obviously you want it. Here, nice doggy." and "Your low battery indicator flashes, so I will show you the power outlet. Nice robby."
The point is that if something begs for a sausage AND has a low battery indicator, then you can charge AND feed it - without first being told that there are not only biological dogs and robodogs, but newly invented cyborgdogs.
(Sorry if this is scary, but it is for illustrating.)

The indicators of whether food or electricity is needed can be implemented in the base class, avoiding any changes to existing dog code. The API is meaningful for anything you can hold in a kennel (and can be abstracted to any class hierarchy with sets of potentially meaningful/-less operations).

To implement this concept, you can add virtual checker methods to the base class, which allow the kennel to find out what the dog needs. With a default implementation of those methods, all existing biological dogs will learn to give the right info on their needs, without the necessity to change their implementation.

For robots (which have not yet been implemented by anybody) you can require behavior of the needs-checkers which is different from the default.

```
class Dog {
public:
    Dog()
    {

    }

    virtual ~Dog()
    {

    }

    virtual void eatFood() = 0;
    virtual void takeBath() = 0;
    virtual void play() = 0;
    virtual void sleep() = 0;

    virtual bool boNeedsFood(void)
    {return true; /* standard dog */
    }

    virtual bool boNeedsElectricity(void)
    {return false; /* standard dog */
    }

    virtual void rechargeBattery(void)
    {    /* optional exception handling, in case kennel is malfunctioning */;
         /* sorry for the mental image... */
    }
};

class robodog
: public dog
{

public:

    /* ... */ 

    virtual bool boNeedsFood(void)
    {    return false; /* standard dog */
    }

    virtual bool boNeedsElectricity(void)
    {    return true; /* standard dog */
    }

    virtual void eatFood(void)
    {/* optional exception handling, in case kennel is malfunctioning */;}

    virtual void rechargeBattery(void)
    {
        /* actual code */
    }

}

/* ... somewhere in kennel ... */

if (doginstance.needsFood())
{doginstance.eatFood();
} /* intentionally no "else", could be cyborg dog, which needs both */
if (doginstance.needsElectricity())
{ doginstance.rechargeBattery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Dog {
public:
    virtual ~Dog()
    {
    }

    virtual void eatFood() = 0;
    virtual void takeBath() = 0;
    virtual void play() = 0;
    virtual void sleep() = 0;
};

class RoboticDog : public Dog {
public:
    virtual void rechargeBattery() = 0;
};

class Pug : public Dog {
private:
    void eatFood()
    {
    }

    void takeBath()
    {
    }

    void play()
    {
        cout << "Pug::play()" << endl;
    }

    void sleep()
    {
    }
};

class Robo1 : public RoboticDog {
private:
    void eatFood()
    {
    }

    void takeBath()
    {
    }

    void play()
    {
        cout << "Robo1::play()" << endl;
    }

    void sleep()
    {
    }

    void rechargeBattery()
    {
        cout << "Robo1::rechargeBattery()" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Pug pug;
    Robo1 robo1;

    Dog *dogs[] = { &pug, &robo1 };

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(dogs) / sizeof(Dog *); ++i) {
        dogs[i]->play();

        RoboticDog *robo = dynamic_cast<RoboticDog *>(dogs[i]);
        if(robo) // If dynamic_cast<> returned != nullptr, this is a RoboticDog
            robo->rechargeBattery();
    }
}
```

This code allows for binary compatibility with your existing clients. Their code will continue to work as-is, and new code can implement the `RoboticDog` interface, which is backwards-compatible with `Dog`.

[`dynamic_cast<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) safely converts pointers and references to classes up, down, and sideways along the inheritance hierarchy. What that means is that if the object you have an interface pointer to implements another interface as well, `dynamic_cast<SecondInterface *>(pointerToFirstInterface)` will return `nullptr` if the underlying object does *not* implement `SecondInterface`.

So you can simply modify your code to check if the `Dog *` pointers you were previously working with happen to point to objects that are really `RoboticDog`s, and if they are, then you're free to use the full `RoboticDog` interface with them.

That's pretty much how they're extending interfaces in COM+ (where you can see a bunch of `SomeInterfaceEx` and `ThatInterface2` abstract classes).